# How you can remove post by clicking on delete button using Id?

Tags: javascript, mysql, database, axios, crud

```
         cancelUserApplication(){

        }
```

how can I make this button take the id of the post that I want?

I'm working with MySQL and Axios if this important for you.

```
 export default class Aplications extends React.Component {

  state = {
applications: [],
deletePostId:0
}
}

         cancelUserApplication(){

        }
    render() {
       <div>
    <Card className="post">
      <CardBody>
        <CardTitle> @company-Username</CardTitle>
        <CardSubtitle>Company Name : {job.companyId}</CardSubtitle>
        <CardText>Job Title : {job.jobTitle}</CardText>
      </CardBody>
      <CardImg
        width="100%"
        src="https://reactstrap.github.io/assets/318x180.svg"
        alt="company image"
      />
      <CardBody>
        <CardLink className="postButton" href="#">
          cancel
        </CardLink>
        <CardLink
          onClick={this.openModal.bind(this)}
          className="postButton"
          href="#"
        >
          View more
        </CardLink>
      </CardBody>
    </Card>
    {/* create modal to show more info */}
    <Modal isOpen={this.state.modalIsopen}>
      <ModalHeader toggle={this.toggleModal.bind(this)}>
        {job.jobTitle}
      </ModalHeader>
      <ModalBody>{job.Description}</ModalBody>
      <ModalFooter>
        <Button onClick={this.cancelUserApplication.bind(this)} color="danger">Cancel Application </Button>
        <Button onClick={this.closeModal.bind(this)} color="secondary">
          Close
        </Button>
      </ModalFooter>
    </Modal>
  </div>
));
return (
  <div>
    {listAppli}
  </div>
);
```

}
}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am having a hard time trying to figure out what your component does. You have both `render` and `return` implemented. For class-based component you have, you should only implement `render`.

Getting back to the origin question, you can implement it in a similar fashion by passing id as an argument:

```js
<Button onClick={() => this.cancelUserApplication(userId)}  color="danger">Cancel Application </Button>
```

then in your function:

```js
function cancelUserApplication(userId) {
  // do stuff; userId is available as a variable
}
```

**update 1**

I added example using React Hooks:

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [items, _] = useState([{ id: 3 }, { id: 2 }, { id: 1 }]);

  function printItemId(id) {
    console.log(items[id]);
  }
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h3>My items:</h3>
      {items.map((item) => (
        <button onClick={() => printItemId(item.id)}>Print item ID!!</button>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: I have tried it In a lot of ways but it still doesn't work

Comment: Added example in the original post.